# File IO reading multiple types from a file

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io, io

Lets say I have a text file like this

```
6 3
john
dan
lammar
```

I can read the numbers, and i can read the names only if they are in separate files. But here the numbers and the names are in a one file. How do i ignore the first line and start reading straight from the second one ?

```
int main()
{
vector<string> names;
fstream myFile;
string line;
int x,y;
myFile.open("test.txt");
    //Im using this for reading the numbers
while(myFile>>x>>y){}
//Would use this for name reading if it was just names in the file
while(getline(myFile,line))
    names.push_back(line);
cout<<names[0];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code snippet? That will help to understand where to make improvement.

Comment: You can always just read everything in and separate out what you don't want later on.

Comment: Your only problem is the first while. keep the myFile>>x>>y; and lose the while around it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I got you right but if you always want to skip the first line - you can simply skip it?

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> names;
    fstream myFile;
    string line;
    int x,y;
    myFile.open("test.txt");
    //skip the first line
    myFile>>x>>y;
    //Would use this for name reading if it was just names in the file
    while(getline(myFile,line))
    names.push_back(line);
    cout<<names[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fstream just call the ignore() method:

```
istream&  ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );
```

so it became very easy:

```
ifstream file(filename);
file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    // ignore the first line

// read the second line
string name; getline(flie, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("test.txt");
    if( myFile.is_open() )
    {
        std::string line;

        if (std::getline(myFile, line))
        {
            std::istringstream strm(line);

            int x, y;
            strm >> x >> y;

            while (std::getline(myFile, line))
                names.push_back(line);
        }

        myFile.close();

        if( !names.empty() )
            std::cout << names[0];
    }
    return 0;
}
```